# AMP script bar code: how to introduce email of the subscriber?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, barcode

I have this code:

```
<p>
<img style='width: 400px; height: 200px' title=barcode border=0 hspace=0 alt=barcode src='%%=BarCodeURL('BBY01-397101069285','Code128Auto', 400, 200, 0)=%%' width=400 height=200>
</p>
```

which generates correctly the bar code in email.
What I need is to put the subscriber email instead of BBY01-397101069285.
I tried with '%%emailaddr%%', %%emailaddr%%, 'emailaddr', unfortunately nothing works.
Any idea how I could insert the email address in the code?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please use the `{}` tool in the editor, or wrap in triple backticks (```) to format your code so it's readable, and make sure to apply relevant tags like `ampscript`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attribute value from your sendable data extension and then utilize that into this bar code generating function. See below:

1. Assuming your sendable data extension has an Email field (to send emails with subscribers' email addresses), let's say the field name is 'Email'.
2. In your email, use this code to generate bar code.

   ```
    %%[ 
         var @barcode, @email 
         set @email = AttributeValue("Email") 
         set @barcode = BarcodeURL(@email, "Code128Auto", 300, 100) 

      ]%%
   ```
3. This will generate the bar code. To display it in the email, you can use this code:

   ```
    <p>
        Barcode: 
       <img src="%%=v(@barcode)=%%">
   </p>
   ```

Please refer [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_generate_barcodes_in_emails.htm&type=5).

Comment: OMG, it worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to StackExchange! If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.